# Getting the command line interpreter

Tags: c#, .net, windows, shell, unix

My [application](https://github.com/IllidanS4/iotools/tree/master/imgio) takes a string command and repeatedly executes it during some process, each time with different environment variables. To support any kind of command, I run `cmd /C` with the command specified and the system takes care of parsing and running the command. However, I think about making the application compatible with Unix .NET implementations by calling `sh -c` instead on these systems.

So, I want to determine two things in the most portable way - the proper interpreter that should be executed (`cmd` on Windows, `sh` or possibly user-specified on Unix) and the style of variables which it accepts (`%var%` on Windows, `$var` on Unix).

At the moment, I think about checking the `COMSPEC` environment variable if it points to a Windows-style command-line interpreter and use that, or look for the `SHELL` variable and use that. Is there a better managed alternative, or is this sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled on checking the `SHELL` and `COMSPEC` environment variables to find the correct interpreter and its specification.

```
static void GetSystemShell(out bool comspec, out string fileName, out string arguments)
{
    fileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC");
    if(fileName != null)
    {
        comspec = true;
    }else{
        fileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SHELL");
        if(fileName != null)
        {
            comspec = false;
        }else{
            fileName = "cmd";
            comspec = true;
        }
    }

    if(comspec)
    {
        arguments = "/C";
    }else{
        arguments = "-c";
    }
}
```

It prefers a `COMSPEC`-compatible interpreter if both variables are set. There are also differences between how passing a command to the interpreter works, `SHELL` expects the command as one (properly escaped) argument, while `COMSPEC` works best simply by wrapping the command in additional quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding something here, but why not use `System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform`?

Comment: A possible solution, but not really that portable. It would only tell me whether I should look for a `COMSPEC` or `SHELL` variable to find the exact command-line interpreter.